# Conserved quantities in GR and duality

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, metric-tensor, symmetry, vector-fields

In many textbooks, the discussion of conserved quantities in General Relativity has the following conclusions:

> If we assuming a spherically symmetric spacetime in the form
>
> \begin{equation} \mathrm{d}s^2 = -\mathrm{e}^{2 \phi}\mathrm{d}t^2
>  -\mathrm{e}^{2 \lambda}\mathrm{d}r^2 +r^2 \mathrm{d}\Omega^2 \quad , \end{equation}
>
> **The fact that the metric is independent of $t$ implies that the $0$
>   component of the momentum, $p_0 :=-E$, is conserved.** ($\phi$ and
>   $\lambda$ are functions of $r$ and $\theta$ only).

The fact that we treat the covariant component (and not the contravariant one) of the momentum as the conserved energy is just a meaningless convention or there is a more physical reason for that?

Comment: It is important. If $p_0$ is constant and $\phi$ depends on position then the contravariant component $p^0 = -\exp(-2\phi) p_0$ won't be constant in general.

Comment: But if I started working with the inverse metric instead, wouldn't I arrive at the same conclusion? I.e, that $p^0$ is conserved and that $p_0$ depends on the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (a little) more to it than that. The fact that the metric does not explicitly depend on $t$ (the first coordinate), means that

$$k^\mu = (-1,0,0,0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$

is a Killing vector. I.e.

$$\nabla_\mu k_\nu+ \nabla_\nu k_\mu =0$$

(It is a good idea to check that for yourself.) This property implies that $p_\mu k^\mu$ is consverved along any geodesic. (Again it is instructive to try to prove this yourself.) Of course, in this particular case $p_\mu k^\mu = -p_0$, leading to the conclusion that $p_0$ is consverved.

However, $p^0$ is not conserved because $k’_\mu = (1,0,0,0)$ is *not* a Killing (co)vector. (This is again easy to check explicitly.)

Comment: I knew about Killing vectors, but I always thought (naively) that if there was a Killing vector there would be also a corresponding Killing covector.

Comment: @delta_omega Note that if $k_\mu$ is a Killing covector, in the sense that $\nabla_\mu k_\nu + \nabla_\nu k_\mu = 0$, then certainly the corresponding vector $k^\mu = g^{\mu \nu} k_\nu$ is a Killing vector in the sense that $\nabla^\mu k^\nu + \nabla^\nu k^\mu = 0$ --- this you can easily check using the 'covariantly constant' property of the metric. What's important, however, is that $k^\mu = (-1,0,0,0)$ is *not* the raised index version of $k'_\mu = (1,0,0,0)$ --- these describe two *different* vector fields. Only the former is a Killing vector field.